# Changed index.js but still seeing old version

Tags: workbox

I am using workbox 4.1.0.

My workbox-config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "web/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{html,js,gawk,png,gif,jpg,jpeg,txt,css,ts}"
  ],
  "swDest": "web/sw.js",
};
```

I create web/sw.js with the following command:

```
workbox generateSW workbox-config.js
```

I can see by the Chrome debug / Application / Service Workers window that it's running fine.  And it works off-line.  My problem is that:

1. I changed index.js
2. I re-ran generateSW

No matter what I do, I am still seeing the original/old index.js file. (I am running online now.) I can't seem to get it to see the modified index.js.  I checked sw.js and index.js is listed.

Sure appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Blake McBride

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem.  The problem is that I am still getting the old version from the normal browser cache.  If I clear that, I get the new version.  So, all I need to do is implement normal logic (versioning) to deal with that.